# Select rows in each group based on their values

Tags: r, row

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Site=c("Site1","Site1","Site1", "Site2","Site2","Site2")
Gender=c("Male","Male","Male","Female","Male","Female")
Tissue=c("Muscle","Muscle","Muscle","Muscle","WB","Muscle")
Element=c("Iron","Iron","Humid","Iron","Humid","Iron")
Result=c(12,22,61,14,52,11)

df=data.frame(Site,Gender,Tissue,Element,Result)

> df

   Site Gender Tissue Element Result
1 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     12
2 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     22
3 Site1   Male Muscle   Humid     61
4 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     14
5 Site2   Male     WB   Humid     52
6 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     11
```

**First Step**

I want to group my data based on Site, Gender and Tissue. Then, within each group, I want to find those rows whose Elements of the same name have a higher Result.

For example,

Group1: Site1 Male Muscle

Group2: Site2 Female Muscle

Group3: Site2 Male WB

Now, in group 1:

Site1 Male Muscle **Iron** 12

Site1 Male Muscle **Iron** 22

Iron is the same Element in two rows. I want to choose the row whose Iron's Result is greater which is

Site1 Male Muscle Iron **22**

Then I want to add another column to the data frame, let's say "Col6", and put the greatest Result amount there. So my data would look like this:

```
   Site Gender Tissue Element Result Col6
1 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     12   NA 
2 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     22   22
3 Site1   Male Muscle   Humid     61   NA
4 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     14   14
5 Site2   Male     WB   Humid     52   NA
6 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     11   NA
```

**Second Step**

After this, I want to multiply the row with the lowest Result for each Element by the Results of "Humid".

For example, in group 1:

Site1 Male Muscle **Iron** 12

Site1 Male Muscle **Iron** 22

Iron is the same Element in two rows with the first row having lower Result **12**:

Site1 Male Muscle Iron **12**

I want to multiply 12 by the Result of Humid in that group which is 61:

Site1 Male Muscle **Humid** 61.

And add this amount (12*61=732) to Col6 in front of Iron (not Humid), so that my final table looks like this:

```
   Site Gender Tissue Element Result Col6
1 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     12  732
2 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     22   22
3 Site1   Male Muscle   Humid     61   NA
4 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     14   14
5 Site2   Male     WB   Humid     52   NA
6 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     11   NA
```

**Note:** Please note that I have tens of Sites and Element types and each group always has two rows of the same Element to pick between lower and higher Result value.

Comment: Why you are not updating the last row which is the lowest for 'Site2'

Comment: I am not sure why the last value is not present.  Otherwise, `df %>% group_by(Site, Gender, Tissue) %>% mutate(Col6 = case_when(Result == max(Result[Element == "Iron"]) ~ Result)) %>% group_by(Site) %>% mutate(Col6 = coalesce(Col6, case_when(Result == min(Result)  ~ Result * Result[Element == 'Humid'])))`

Comment: Actually your data is not sufficient for problem.  There isn't a row available for `Humid` value for `Ste2, Female, Muscle`? Further it is not clear how many rows can a group for one element may be there in the data (at max 2 or more)?? Whatif there are more than one Humid for each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is maximum of one Humid row for each group (or else it will take max of that humid group), follow this code.  A separate column `dummy` has been added for ease of explanation.  Moreover I have one extra row (site2, Female, Muscle) for a better demonstration.

```
#revised sample

Site=c("Site1","Site1","Site1", "Site2","Site2","Site2", "Site2")
Gender=c("Male","Male","Male","Female","Male","Female", "Female")
Tissue=c("Muscle","Muscle","Muscle","Muscle","WB","Muscle", "Muscle")
Element=c("Iron","Iron","Humid","Iron","Humid","Iron", "Humid")
Result=c(12,22,61,14,52,11, 50)

df=data.frame(Site,Gender,Tissue,Element,Result)

> df
   Site Gender Tissue Element Result
1 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     12
2 Site1   Male Muscle    Iron     22
3 Site1   Male Muscle   Humid     61
4 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     14
5 Site2   Male     WB   Humid     52
6 Site2 Female Muscle    Iron     11
7 Site2 Female Muscle   Humid     50
```

## Code

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Site, Gender, Tissue, Element) %>%
  mutate(dummy = case_when(Element != "Humid" & Result == max(Result) ~ "Max_E",
                           Element != "Humid" & Result != max(Result) ~ "Other_E",
                           Element == "Humid" & Result == max(Result) ~ "AA_Max_H",
                           TRUE ~ "Other_H")) %>%
  ungroup(Element) %>% arrange(Site, Gender, Tissue, dummy) %>%
  mutate(col6 = case_when(dummy == "Max_E" ~ Result,
                          dummy == "Other_E" ~ Result * first(Result[dummy == "AA_Max_H"]),
                          TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% arrange(rowid) %>%
  select(-rowid, -dummy)

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  Site  Gender Tissue Element Result  col6
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Site1 Male   Muscle Iron        12   732
2 Site1 Male   Muscle Iron        22    22
3 Site1 Male   Muscle Humid       61    NA
4 Site2 Female Muscle Iron        14    14
5 Site2 Male   WB     Humid       52    NA
6 Site2 Female Muscle Iron        11   550
7 Site2 Female Muscle Humid       50    NA
```

For the sample data posted by OP, it gives the desired results exactly

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Site  Gender Tissue Element Result  col6
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Site1 Male   Muscle Iron        12   732
2 Site1 Male   Muscle Iron        22    22
3 Site1 Male   Muscle Humid       61    NA
4 Site2 Female Muscle Iron        14    14
5 Site2 Male   WB     Humid       52    NA
6 Site2 Female Muscle Iron        11    NA
```